# Odd results from simple group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

The code below is returning extra information I am not expecting. Is this an issue or am I missing something?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol':['A','B','C'],
                   'volume':[561,56,8]})

group = df.groupby('symbol')

def f1(group):
    print group
    return group

group.apply(f1)
```

**I am getting:**

```
  symbol  volume  
0      A     561  
  symbol  volume  
0      A     561  
  symbol  volume  
1      B      56  
  symbol  volume  
2      C       8
```

As you can see my issue is with the print statement. I am getting group "A" twice and I am not sure if this is a bug. Can someone confirm?

Pandas version : '0.14.1'

Comment: That's not the normal way to do that, see docs here:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

> Warning: In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the
>   first group to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path.
>   This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they
>   will take effect twice for the first group.

That's why your method is called once on the first group. It's by-implementation.